# How to check disk space utilization from remote server?

Tags: batch-file

I need to get the details of disk space for all server from one server.

eg: I have 4 server (1111,2222,3333,4444) I need to get the details of four server from 1111 server. Is it possible? First need to enter into the  server and need to be check the disk space utilization.

My code:

```
start servername
wmic /node: SERVERIP get size freesize caption
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the server IPs in a text file, one on each line, use something like:

```
@echo off
for /f %%s in (servers.txt) do (
    echo "Processing server: %%s"
    wmic /node:"%%s" volume get SystemName,DriveLetter,Capacity,FreeSpace,Label,Status
)
```

Comment: I tried this code I m not getting the output .please help me out.thanks in advance.

Comment: when I put server IP and trying to run then I am getting error as access denied please help me out

Comment: Run it from an account which has administrative privileges on the remote servers. e.g. start -> command prompt -> right click -> "run as" -> an administrative logon.

Comment: I run as administrator but I am getting access deined